# NDB: query on multiple parents given a cursor

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I can't understand if this is possible or not.

I need to retrieve all the entities of kind "A", children of a list of entities of kind "B".

So there are multiple children "A" for each entity "B".

This would be easy: i get B-list, the list of entities of kind "B" that i need and for each, i  get the list of childrens.

Now, i could sort them after the query, merging them in a single list even if it's not a good practice. My biggest problem is that i don't know how to use a cursor because there are multiple queries.

Then i think i need something that looks like

```
A.query(ancestor in B-list).fetch(...)
```

but i can't understand how i can do that or what i should use.

Answer (score 5):

You can only specify one query per ancestor.  So you'll have to do multiple queries.  But if you're a little clever you can do them in parallel.  Here's a rough sketch of the code (untested):

```
futures = []
for b in B_list:
  futures.append(A.query(ancestor=b).fetch_async(...))
results = []
for f in futures:
  results.extend(f.get_result())
```

Comment: The other part of the question was about cursors.  The op could return a cursor for each of the queries (name each cursor to match query it belongs to) and pass that list back when needing to get next set of results.

Comment: @Bert i'm not sure how it should work. What if i add a KeyProperty to A and link directly to "B"? How bad it is for performances?

Comment: Ah, that's actually clever, and Bert is right that I missed that part.  If you had a KeyProperty in A (redundantly) referencing its ancestor, you *could* use the .IN() method and cursors, as long as you added .order(A._key) to the query.  The extra cost shouldn't be too bad, it's one extra index op per entity write.  Downside is that your queries might return stale results right after a write of one of the affected entities; you wouldn't have that problem with ancestor queries.  Also you couldn't do it in a transaction.  But that may be the least of your problems.